# How many verb forms are there?

Tags: verbs

Somebody told me that there are 5 forms of verbs, for eg:
V1- eat 
V2- ate 
V3- eaten 
V4- eating 
V5- ?? 
What is the 5th form?

Comment: People who have not studied English as a second language are not usually familiar with numbering forms like this. But you have left out "eats". I have no idea what number it would be.

Comment: @ColinFine: I'd never really thought about it like this before, but isn't it true that there are at most 4 different "tense" variations for a verb (*eat* = unmarked infinitive, *ate* = past simple, *eaten* = past participle, and *eating* = continuous participle)? And the unmarked infinitive also serves as *present* for all except 3rd person singular, where it's "inflected" to *eats*.

Comment: Indeed, @FumbleFingers: there are always either three or four (often the PP is identical with the P, and occasionally with the Pres). "Be" is the only case where the base form is not identical to the (non 3s) present form; and that one has another two forms - _am_ and _were_, making 8 in all.

Comment: @ColinFine: Ah! I be forgetting about ***to be**!* Maybe OP is thinking "Maximum 5 "basic" variations **plus** up to three inflections for "person" in the present tense". Or maybe someone is just "misinformed".

Comment: Virtually all lexical verbs have a paradigm with six forms: preterite ("He _ate_ fish), 3rd person singular ("He _eats_ fish"), plain present ("They _eat_ fish"), plain form ("He should _eat_ fish"), gerund-participle ("He is _eating_ fish"), past participle ("He has _eaten_ fish"). "Be" is the exception with a total of 13 forms.

Comment: @BillJ: how do you get 13? I make 8. Even if you include the obsolete 2s forms, that's only another 3: _art_, _wast_, _wert_.

Comment: @ColinFine I suspect you may have omitted the five negative forms "aren't" (1st sg), "aren't" (other), "isn't", "wasn't" and "weren't". They are part of the paradigm.

Comment: @BillJ: ah, right. Thank you. That means that _have_, _do_, and most of the modals and semimodals also have extra forms.

Comment: Yes, "can", for example has "can't" and "couldn't, and auxiliary "have" has an extra negative form, the 3rd sing present tense form "hasn't".

Comment: Linguistic analyses such as these are worthless to someone who doesn't yet know how  to use them. "How long has he been sitting there eating that hotdog?"

Answer (score 2):

In one analysis there are 5 forms of most verbs

Plain  **eat**  (used in
infinitive *To eat*,
present tense *I eat the fish*,
imperative *Eat your fish*,
subjunctive *It was required that he eat the fish*,
and with modals  *He can eat*)

Past **ate** (I ate the fish)

Past participle  *The **eaten** fish*, (used in perfect "I have eaten the fish" and passive forms "The fish was eaten by the cat")

Present participle *The **eating** fish* (used in continuous tenses, "I am eating the fish" and as a gerund "Eating fish is good for you")

Third person singular **eats**  (He eats fish)

For many verbs the past tense form and the past participle form are identical (but can be distinguished from context)

> I played/I have played

And some verbs, such as modal verbs, miss some forms

> The verb "can" has a past tense "could", but no participles, and no special third person form)

Some verbs have more forms, eight for the verb "to be":

> Be: am, is, are;  was, were; been, being (+ isn't, aren't, wasn't, weren't)

However much of the variation in the verb phrase in English is not in the forms of the verb, but in the use of various auxiliaries and helping modal verbs

> Can eat, will eat, would have eaten, might eat, do eat, did not eat, could not have eaten, used to eat,... and many more

Comment: The plain form "eat" and the 3rd sing form are separate forms, thus there are six in total. The negative forms of "be" are part of its paradigm ("aren't" (1st sg), "aren't" (other), "isn't", "wasn't" and "weren't", making 13 in total.

Comment: Yes, the plain form "eat" and the third singular "eats" are different.  That makes 5.  Unless you claim that the plain form "eat" and the present "eat" are different. This seems hard to justify on morphological grounds alone. The negatives forms can be argued to be clitics, but I'll mention them

Comment: But you distinguish aren't and aren't.  I do not see any grounds for doing so based on the form of the word alone, only on the context in which it is placed.

Comment: Yes, though the plain present and the plain form have the same shape, they occur in different kinds of clause, and hence should be distinguished in the paradigm. The negative "aren't" occurs as a 1st singular and elsewhere.

Comment: "aint" should probably be mentioned at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I go over this in [my answer to the ELU question *In how many inflectional forms can a verb be written English?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/440203/77227)

The fifth inflected form that you are missing is simply *eats,* the form used for the present-tense third-person singular.